# Difference between modifying a function parameter and modifying a local variable

Tags: c, function, linked-list

I saw a function that takes a list and a function pointer, and applies this
function to each element of the list.

**ft_list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct  s_list
{
    struct s_list *next;
    void    *data;
}       t_list;
#endif
```

**ft_list_foreach.c**

```
void    ft_list_foreach(t_list *begin_list, void (*f) (void *))
{
    t_list  *curr;

    curr = begin_list;
    while (curr)
    {
        (*f)(curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

But why declare t_list *curr ? And not just increment begin_list until the end of the linked list(NULL) ?

Comment: You can increment begin_list it will work aswell.

Comment: What is the advantage to declare t_list *curr ?

Comment: There is none :)

Comment: And.. it's likely you'll get exactly the same assembly in the two cases

Comment: Since parameters are passed by value in C, changing the `begin_list` parameter cannot affect the value of the variable in the outer scope. Changing the value pointed by `begin_list` would be visible, but this is not what you're doing here. A good idea is to make this parameter a pointer to const, i.e. `void ft_list_foreach(const t_list *begin_list, void (*f) (void *))`, and do this for all function where you expect to have read-only access to the list.

Comment: @Fredrik *You can increment begin_list it will work aswell.*  You don't mean `begin_list++;` or something like that, do you?

Comment: @Andrew no with ->next ofcourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although in this case declaring a new variable which holds the pointer to the list makes no difference, I would say that this is a good practice to never mutate the function parameters, only when the function's nature requires to do so (i.e. when you have an inout parameter, like a buffer). This unwritten rule will save you from a lot of problems in future when dealing with more complex functions.

Consider just a simple case where you would need for some reason to also destroy and free the contents of this list after applying the `f` function. Of course, in this simple example you would easily spot the issue, but there are cases when this wouldn't be that obvious.

So, again, even though here it makes no difference, I strongly recommend to always write your functions using this pattern and this will avoid a lot of weird and unexpected issues.

Comment: This expresses a common, reasonable position.  It should be noted, however, that although it is common, and although it is a plausible explanation for the code presented in the question (+1) , this position is not *universal*.

Answer (score 1):

A function can be designed to return a value, although there is technically no explicit need to so, when passing a pointer to an object
as argument to modify it in the function.

The reason for this is when you have a critical operation inside of the function, and there is an error with this operation, you can return a specific value to the caller to symbolize that an error occurred inside of the function.

I guess the author later (half) optimized the code of the function here as his/her first intent maybe was to add such a security mechanism or even prepare the code to maybe later add this if the function becomes more critical features.

It is a technique that you return the passed pointer, when the operations in the function were successful and f.e. `NULL` at an error.

Also a common technique is to reassign the passed pointer with the returned pointer value, although this is risky since you lose the reference in the caller completely if an error occurred in the called function.

Since you increment the pointer in the function, it would be not very good to return the incremented pointer as one might want to reassign the passed pointer with the return value, like:

```
int *p = //anything ;
p = foo(p);
```

You need to either store the passed pointer value inside of another separate pointer variable, increment this "copy" pointer and return the passed parameter variable

OR

store the value of the passed pointer into another local pointer variable, increment the parameter pointer and return the "copy" pointer.

Therefore it can make sense to use `curr` instead of `begin_list` to increment and use `begin_list` as return value at success.

Otherwise `NULL` if an error occurred.

Note that you need to change the return type from `void` to `t_list *` then.

---

Also:

> Difference between modifying a function parameter and modifying a local variable

A *parameter* is a local variable.